# How to show a list of different objects (children) in WPF and bind a button inside the list to each row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

How to show a list of different objects (children) in WPF and bind a button inside the list to each row?
I have got 4 classes: Person(parent), Student(Child of Person), Staff(Child of Person) Teacher(Child of Staff)

In View:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0"  Name="List" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PeopleList}" SelectedItem="{Binding RowSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="180" x:Name="Column_Type" 
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="180"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="180">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <dx:SimpleButton Content="SELECT" Width="180" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCommand, ElementName=Column_Type}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Column_Type, Path=Type}"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

in ViewModel:

```
    #region Select

    DelegateCommand<Person> selectCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<Person> SelectCommand
    {
        get => selectCommand ??
               (selectCommand = new DelegateCommand<Person>(Select, CanSelect));
    }
    public bool CanSelect(Person rowItemType)
    {
        if (rowItemType.Type == "Teacher" || rowItemType.Type == "Student")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void Select(Person selectedItem)
    {
     //if(RowSelectedItem.Type == "Staff")
     //   RowSelectedItem.
        //Refresh();
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: You can make a DelegateCommand in each of the ViewModels for the different objects (Person, Student etc...) and instead of `DataContext.SelectCommand` markup just put `SelectCommand`. No need for the `ElementName=Column_Type` in this case.

Comment: You are binding `Person.Type` as command parameter, but your execute and canExecute methods have a `Person` as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind IsEnabled property and use a Converter,

in XAML:

```
<Button Content="SELECT"
    Width="180"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource TypeConverter}}" />
```

and new converter:

```
public class TypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isPerson = value is Person;
        return isPerson;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simplified answer, your scenario will more than likely will be far more complex but it illustrates what I wrote in the comment above.

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PeopleList}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="180">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Content="SELECT" Width="180" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public Collection<object> PeopleList => new Collection<object>
        {
            new Person(),
            new Student(),
            new Person(),
            new Student()
        };
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
using System;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    internal class Person
    {
        DelegateCommand selectCommand;

        public string Type => "Person";

        public string FullName => "My name is person";

        public DelegateCommand SelectCommand
        {
            get => selectCommand ?? (selectCommand = new DelegateCommand(Select, CanSelect));
        }
        public bool CanSelect()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Select()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Person Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Student.cs

```
using System;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    internal class Student
    {
        DelegateCommand selectCommand;

        public string Type => "Student";

        public string FullName => "My name is student";

        public DelegateCommand SelectCommand
        {
            get => selectCommand ?? (selectCommand = new DelegateCommand(Select, CanSelect));
        }

        public bool CanSelect()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void Select()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

If you were wanting some logic to be done in the *MainWindow.xaml.cs* you can have an event in *Person.cs* & *Student.cs* and 'hook' these up when the objects are created and added to the the `PeopleList` collection.

Comment: Thank you for your response bro; but as I am doing with MVVM pattern I would like to put all logic in the ViewModel. so I have to send a parameter from View.xaml by SelectCommand like "Type" to the ViewModel.cs; so do you know how to send the parameter "Type"(which is a property in Person.cs(parent)) from the button in View.xaml to the SelectCommand in ViewModel.cs in order to recognize the type of person of each row?

Comment: The same applies, the logic in my example for MainWindow.xaml.cs just becomes logic for the MainViewModel.cs for the View. So the Person.cs, Student.cs etc...become child ViewModels, or simply Models in this case and they can handle the button event and event up to the MainViewModel if needed. I didn't want to over complicate the example.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer; but I don't want to write three SelectCommand separately for each class. actually, I want to write only one SelectCommand in ViewModel and by one property as a parameter to recognize the type